# Create filter on html file chooser dialog

Tags: html, openfiledialog

Is there a way to show only .xxx files in the default file chooser dialog.
xxx may be not-known file types, such as abc, efg etc.

I'm using html5 so it may have new support for this type of things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The [HTML 5 `accept` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#attr-input-accept) on `file` input elements is for this purpose. E.g.:

```
<input type="file" accept=".doc,.docx,.xml,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document">
```

Answer (score 9):

For others arriving here, these are some very handy predefined sets:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*"/>
<input type="file" accept="video/*"/>
<input type="file" accept="audio/*"/>
```