# How to restrict Input[file] by particular extension in file select pop-up?

Tags: html

I want to select only particular file extension types and also only those files can be visible when upload button click and pop-up opened, instead of ALL Files, only allowed files will show.

i have used accept attribute and file types but none working. Kindly help if any one can :)

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835883/create-filter-on-html-file-chooser-dialog

Comment: @Prisoner `i have used accept attribute and file types but none working.`

Comment: Which browser you tested?