# Choose file from computer and get the filepath

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to use something like input type=file where I can choose a file on my computer and then get the filepath? I use HTML5, JQ/JS

EDIT: If it's possible with C# I can use that as well.

I just want a HTML-button that is clicked on and then the user can browse file, and that filepath is what I want

Comment: And what have you done with HTML5,JQ/JS so far??

Comment: If you mean the filepath on the user's computer I don't think so, that would cause security issues.

Comment: or you also might find this info useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835883/create-filter-on-html-file-chooser-dialog

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I have editet the question.

Comment: @Chevi no, I want something like that. Not that. Because as far as I read its impossible

Comment: also see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/2200120/648350

Comment: I'm going to use the filepath to read a file using OleDB

Comment: I think you might be able to get the path using a Flash based uploader, since they circumvent most of the browser's security measures.

Comment: Is there not any other way? Use something else instead of input type=file ?

Comment: Like a complement for the users (instead of just writing in the filepath...)

Answer (score 0):

html5 support a [file API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/)

```
if (window.File && window.FileList) {
    $(element)[0].files;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve it is through this

```
<input type="file" name="uploadFile">
```

Then you can use javascript (as mentioned in comment section bellow your original question) to get path. But you won't get full path, modern browsers don't allow that.

You also asked for C# solution, this could work for you:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string path = "C:\\stagelist.txt";
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
        string filenameNoExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
        string root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is I need full path. Otherwise the connectionString for my OleDB won't find the file

Comment: @krillezzz I am afraid there's no other way around that. New browsers dont let you get it.